# Oracle SQL select distinct

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a sample table as follows.

```
ID     Name            Code     Address
----+---------------+--------+----------------
1   |  Sydney Hall  |  SH    |  11 Abc Street
2   |  Sydney Hall  |  SH    |  23 Abc Street
3   |  Main Hall    |  MH    |  74 Xyz Street
4   |  Odyssey Hall |  OH    |  133 AbZ Street
5   |  Odyssey Hall |  OH    |  28 Xyx Street
```

I would like to select distinct Code entries as well as ID and Name for these distinct entries. For the table above I would like to get the following (so I am ignoring the building addresses).

```
ID     Name            Code   
----+---------------+--------+
1   |  Sydney Hall  |  SH
3   |  Main Hall    |  MH
4   |  Odyssey Hall |  OH
```

It's probably a Left Join but I can't seem to put it together properly (especially since I'm selecting data from the same table). Does any one have an idea about this?
Thanks.

Comment: why you are not using distinct name, code then have inner join to same table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [table_1] 
WHERE [ID] IN (SELECT Min([ID]) 
               FROM [table_1] 
               GROUP BY CODE
              )
```

Comment: The full code is `SELECT id, name, code FROM buildings WHERE id IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM tb_buildings GROUP BY Code)`

Answer (score 4):

I see everyone has already answered this, but why so complicated?

```
SELECT 
MIN(ID) ID, 
MIN(NAME) NAME, 
CODE 
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY CODE
```

Comment: This may show data that doesn't necessarily exist in the original data set, e.g. if MIN(ID) = 1 and MIN(NAME) shows data from row where ID = 2.

Comment: Based on the sample dataset it's fine. Based on real data, yes it's probably insufficient.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that I would look at doing this. One is to use the `FIRST` aggregate function ([documented here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm#i1000901)). The syntax is a little confusing but it should do the job

```
Select
  MIN(ID) keep (dense_rank first order by id) as id,
  MIN(NAME) keep (dense_rank first order by id) as name,
  CODE
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY CODE
```

The other alternative method that I would suggest is using the `ROW_NUMBER` function as suggested by @techdo, although I think you would need to remove the NAME column from that answer and instead use:

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CODE order by ID) RNUM, 
      ID, 
      NAME, 
      CODE
    FROM YOUR_TABLE
  )x where RNUM=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one also:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Code  
FROM table 
WHERE ID IN (SELECT Max(ID) 
             FROM table 
             GROUP BY Code
            )
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try:

```
SELECT * FROM(
  SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by NAME, CODE order by NAME, CODE) RNUM, 
      ID, 
      NAME, 
      CODE, 
      ADDRESS 
    FROM YourTABLE
  )x where RNUM=1;
```